# What is the interpretation of Kauśītakī Brāhmaṇa Upaṇiṣad 2:4?

Tags: upanishads

> Kauśītakī Brāhmaṇa Upaṇiṣad 2:4.
>
> Athāto daivaḥ smaro yasya priyo bubhūṣed yasyai vā yeṣām vaiteṣāṁ evaikasmin parvany etayaivāvr̥taita ājyahutīr juhoti
>
> “Now then, the intense longing of love stimulated by the gods. When one desires to be loved by a man or a woman or by men and women, he shall offer to the afore mentioned gods oblations in the sacred fire”.

So what is the correct interpretation of this verse.

Comment: (For those who want to answer) The Upanishad translated by A.G.K.Warrier can read from here: http://www.vedarahasya.net/kaushita.htm

Comment: @TheDestroyer: The answer is fine as is.

Comment: It is probably not talking about sexual love. Or it could be sexual love for the opposite gender.

Comment: @MoziburUllah where is the answer

Comment: @Dark Knight: It's been deleted by Destroyer. I've put back a redited version and taken out the part I was dubious about.

Comment: Most if not all translations done by Western orientalists are wrong as their understanding of Sanskrit was and is limited.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Given that the question has earned -5 votes and my answer has earned 3, I think that your inclination to say that tge "OP asked the correct interpretation" is quite wring. And this is why my answer doesn't mention it. Please reinstate my answer - there is nothing wrong with it. I consider this an abuse of your moderating powers.

Answer (score 4):

Kauśītakī Brāhmaṇa Upaṇiṣad 2:4.

Athāto daivaḥ smaro yasya priyo bubhūṣed yasyai vā yeṣām vaiteṣāṁ evaikasmin parvany etayaivāvr̥taita ājyahutīr juhoti

The in-question provided Translation in Angrezi, is wrong.

It does not mention "longing love"
It mentions the Sacrifice to Help someone.